# Javascript prediction

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide, phpstorm, sublimetext

I'm a huge fan of Sublime text, but I noticed something not that helpful when developing Javascript.

Imagine I have a revealing module pattern

```
var revealingModuleName = (function() {

function methodName() {

};

function test(){

}

return {
    methodName:methodName
};

}());
```

As you may know right now the function test is private, and methodName is public.
Visual studio, aptana and PHPStorm know it, and when I start to type revealingModuleName, after a dot they suggest ONLY the public function (in this case, methodName). This is really helpful to understand the code flow.

Unfortunately if you type exactly the same thing in Sublime Text it suggest methodName AND test too, and that is not correct because the outside of the function don't know anything about a test function.

I'm not english, I hope I'm explaining it right.

Is there any plugin to solve this issue? To turn sublime as smart as Visual Studio, PHP Storm or Aptana?

Comment: You could try [TernJS](http://ternjs.net/)

Comment: Sublime is much different tool than WebStorm / Aptana or any other IDE. It's just quick and easy text editor with nice snippets and focus on performance not features. If you need this type of support from your text editor it's better to switch back to full featured IDE.

Comment: Kuo, unfortunately TernJS didn't change anything.

Daniula, I'm using now PHPStorm. It's an amazing tool but I'm so used to the lightweight of sublime text that other softwares feel so heavy.